# Issue with after payment success redirect on site using pay u money

Tags: php, ssl, https, payumoney

I have an issue with payment success on Pay U Money. If any user made the payment then after payment success its redirect to seller site. Its success return some data for site that data use for update the client payment information on site.

Issue is that before redirect to seller site a confirmation box is popup. If user click cancel or close the browser then site not update for client payment. Any solution for avoid that Confirmation Box. Confirmation box image attach with that.

[image]

Comment: Not the answer you're looking for: I would suggest using a secure connection.. but that's obvious. Now, do you really wanna send confidential information over an insecure connection? I would consider a minimum requirement for a page that process payments to have this info encrypted.

Comment: Please explain more

Comment: I'm not a security expert, but unencrypted data can be captured. Now, in order to confirm that payment for a customer that made a payment, you need to send back to the site at least an identifier for the client and a confirmation of the payment. May look like not so important info, but that info may be enough to social engineer or use other methods and get more information about that account. So, this means you are leaking confidential data. That pop-up windows simply transfers the responsibility to the customer, but doesn't solve the problem. Contact your payment processor for instructions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this is to add an SSL certificate to the site, thereby  making it secure, and not triggering the "insecure" warning box.

There are a number of other benefits to adding an SSL certificate including the fact that [Google is giving a ranking boost to secure sites](http://searchengineland.com/google-starts-giving-ranking-boost-secure-httpsssl-sites-199446).

- [GoDaddy: How to add an SSL Certificate](https://www.godaddy.com/help/install-ssl-certificates-16623)
- [DigiCert: Installing SSL Certificates](https://www.digicert.com/ssl-certificate-installation.htm)
- [DigitalOcean: How to Install an SSL Certificate](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-an-ssl-certificate-from-a-commercial-certificate-authority)

Comment: Sir, If i am use Chrome then that confirmation box not popup without SSL. If i use Firefox then it show.

Comment: @Kashish Agarwal, Great!  You're part way there already then!  Just install an SSL cert and then it won't pop-up at all! :)+

Comment: Ok sir, Thank You.